# Got my Canada PR application approved - cannot leave Ukraine, the visa has already expired, do I have a chance to have my visa re-issued?

Tags: canada, ukraine

I applied for EE (FSW) in 2020 and got it approved in 2022. I am a Ukrainian citizen, male 31, currently in Ukraine, thus cannot leave the country. I sent my passport via courier and got the visa stamped, however, it has expired already. The application is still in the approved state, but I am not sure when the ban on leaving the country will be lifted and whether will I be eligible to come to Canada or not. Do I have a chance to have my visa re-issued and eventually come to live in Canada when the ban is lifted?

Comment: Have you tried contacting [IRCC](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/corporate/contact-ircc/web-form2.html)?

Comment: yes - got general phrases in response, expressions of the concern about the situation, but no particular directions

Answer (score 3):

Normally, once your confirmation of permanent residence expires, you must apply for permanent residence again and qualify based on the criteria in effect at the time of the new application. However, the minister may allow for exceptional circumstances, e.g. COVID-19 travel restrictions.

The Russian invasion of Ukraine definitely counts as an exceptional circumstance worthy of consideration, but at the moment there is no blanket public policy exemption for persons prevented from leaving due to Ukrainian law. An individual appeal may still be made to the Minister.

Comment: But the application is still showing as approved (with only the visa in the documents list showing as expired)

Comment: @lopushen The decision has been made and that particular application is and will always be approved in status. A new examination is needed to issue another PR visa and that examination will be based on the requirements in effect at the time.

Comment: If you are talking about the medical examination - then yes, I realise that. I wonder if I should go through the the whole process (getting into the draw, IELTS, WES, PoF). Also, I am over 30 now, was 28 at the moment of the application, so did not get the points deducted due to age. This will not be the case if I have to go through the process again.

Comment: @lopushen The examination will be of your whole file, including any medical examination required, and more importantly, the express entry invitation, which has now expired. You will need to ask for ministerial relief due to your exceptional circumstances.